# capture submit() method

Tags: javascript, submit, capture

I have a form like:

```
<form method="POST" action="page.html" onsubmit="alert('foo'); // validate();" name="foobar">
...
</form>
```

and a link like:

```
<div onclick="document.foobar.submit();">click me</div>
```

How can I capture the submit() method and call my validate function?

[JsBin example](http://jsbin.com/ulixuy/1/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call method from html itself. modified [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ulixuy/57/edit). Instead of submitting form on click you can call  `submitHandler` and pass form reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(){

    }

    function submitHandler(form){
      validate();
      alert('foo');

}
    window.onload = function(){
        document.foobar.submit = submitHandler;
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="page.html" onsubmit="submitHandler(this);" name="foobar">
      <input type="text" />
    </form>

    <div onclick="document.foobar.submit()">click me</div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds great, but I can't change the submit method. (That is not our code.)

Comment: I can't change the: `<div onclick="document.foobar.submit();" ...`
Do you have any idea without changing this line?

Comment: @SteffenMaas I made the changes. I overrode document.foobar.submit method. is it fine with you?

Answer (score 1):

Uniquely identify your form with an id

```
document.getElementById('formid').onsubmit = function() {
    // You have captured the submit method now do what you need
};
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ulixuy/53/)

Comment: @SteffenMaas, There was a typo in my code. And you are suppose to catch the submit event being triggered, not the execution of submit function.

Comment: I tryed your Demo in FF and Opera, but when I hit the 'click me' link, the alert does not show up.

Comment: @SteffenMaas, Use the submit button to see the alert box. About the link not triggering the submit, I am puzzled at that myself.

Comment: Follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819357/form-submitted-using-submit-from-a-link-cannot-be-caught-by-onsubmit-handler) question to know why `onclick` is not working.

Comment: Ok, with the a click on the submit button, I see the alert box.
I'm curious about your solution about trigging the event. :)

Comment: Oh, sorry a misunderstanding. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery `.submit()` handler.

```
$('form').submit(function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  // Validate function returns false or true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addEventsToHTML(){
    var form = document.getElementById('foobar');
    form.onsubmit = submitHandler;
    function submitHandler(){
        validate();
    }
}
window.onload = addEventsToHTML;
</script>
```